# Android Custom ListView with Checkbox and changing background color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom ListView with Checkboxes and 3 TextViews. Here is my layout for list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listviewitem_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/faxCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/faxbox_item_first_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/faxCheckBox"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/fax_number_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/fax_send_date_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9sp"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/more_fax_info_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/faxCheckBox"
        android:layout_below="@id/faxbox_item_first_row"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also a custom arrayadapter for the listview:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {
    private ArrayList<Order> mOrders;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResourceId;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<Order> orders) {
        super(context, resourceId, orders);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mOrders = orders;
        this.mResourceId = resourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        final Order order = mOrders.get(position);

        if (order != null) {
            TextView sender = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_textView);
            TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.send_date_textView);
            TextView moreInfo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.more_info_textView);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            final int itemPosition = position;
            final RelativeLayout rowLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.listviewitem_layout);

            view.setTag(order.getId());

            if (sender != null) {
                sender.setText(order.getSender());
            }

             rowLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_item_selector);

            if (mSelectedIds.contains(order.getId())) {
                rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9CD7EF"));
            }

            if (date != null) {
                date.setText(Utils.getStringDateForBox(order.getSendDate(), mContext));
            }

            if (moreInfo != null) {
                moreInfo.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.number_of_pages, order.getPages(), order.getPages()));
            }

            if (checkBox != null) {
                checkBox.setTag(order.getId());

                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (mSelectedIds.contains(buttonView.getTag()) == true) {
                            if (isChecked == false) {
                                mSelectedIds.remove(buttonView.getTag());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                mSelectedIds.add((Long) buttonView.getTag());
                            }
                        }

                        showHideActionMode();
                        setActionModeTitle();
                        mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    }
                });

                if (mSelectedIds.contains(order.getId())) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

listview_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@color/blue" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/blue" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
<item android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
     android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The problem is, if I press a row, then it changes the background color to blue, but without checkbox, checbox has all the time the orange background color. How can I change it?
Maybe should I everything differently make? I'd like at the best something like in the gmail app on the ICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find only how to make a custom checkbox, but this is not the best solution.

checbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light" />
```

and in my list item layout I added that to my checkbox:

```
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
```